# Can I turn off Main Thread Checker, and use UIKit on off main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, uikit, grand-central-dispatch

I have a question about calling UI API on background thread.

I need view information to save view, for example, view.center, view.transform, view.frame.width.

And this encode need to execute on background thread, not main thread.

Because this encoding logic has high computation cost, so it affect to response to user interaction (like Apple Pencil inputs).

So I turned off the Main Thread Checker, and calling UI API on background thread.

I don't need any UI updates, but only gathering UIView, UITextView, CALayer's information.

In this case, is there any possible problems that calling UI API on background thread?

There is some warning messages, but I cannot find any problems on debug mode.

Please give any kind of advice about proper way to save view information.

Thank you.

```
    func pendingSave(pending: Bool) {
        if let save = self.pendingRequestSave {
            save.cancel()
        }

        if !pending {
            self.save(workItem: nil)
            return
        }

        self.pendingRequestSave = DispatchWorkItem(qos: .userInitiated, flags: .enforceQoS) { [weak self] in
            self?.save(workItem: self?.pendingRequestSave)
        }

        //savingQueue is serial DispatchQueue
        DrawingViewController.savingQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1),
                                                     execute: self.pendingRequestSave!)
    }

    func save(workItem: DispatchWorkItem?) {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            let jsonData = try! encoder.encode(self.canvasView)
            if workItem == nil || !(workItem!.isCancelled) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    MonthService.save(dateId: self.curMonthInfo, contents: jsonData)
                }
            }
        }
```

[Assert] Unsupported use of UIKit view-customization API off the main thread. -setBackgroundColor: sent to >

Answer (score 1):

Please note that not just UI updates needs to be put in main thread, all UI getters and setters are also required to be called from the main thread, that is why you are having these problems.

In order to solve the issue in a proper way, you need to put the high-computational-cost function inside a background thread, and when calling any UI getter/setter, you need to put it inside the main thread by itself.

Just a recommendation, always keep the main-thread checker enabled, because it saves you lots of time indicating the problem in your logic if it exists.

For example:

```
var array = [String]()

    //High computational block, use operation queue to create a thread
    OperationQueue.init().addOperation {
        for string in array{

            //UI Getter/Setter, use main thread queue
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                textLabel.text = string
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. Then, how to make high-cost function in background to wait until UI getter/setter end (main.async) ?